# TinyMCE with knockout data binding would´t update

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, tinymce

I have the TinyMCE WYSiWYG Editor presenting text depending on a selected object, but experience problem with the binding.

The first "instanciation" seems to work, but when choosing a new text from the drop down list of available text the editor goes blank and Firebug console tells me:

TypeError: D.hasChildNodes is not a function
    ...ute(i),"string"==typeof r){try{r="true"===r?!0:"false"===r?!1:"null"===r?null:+r...

and

NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Unexpected error
    .../,"$1"));return false}});if(!u.getParam("accessibility_focus")){g.add(i.add(k,"a...

I have tried to recreate my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/xc4sz/1/ 
It´s not 100% but at least it does´t work. ;)

If I instead of clicking directly from text 1 to text 2 go via the "Choose option" the text is presented properly.

I guess it has to do with the "init" section below:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().tinymceOptions || {};
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var el = $(element)

        //handle edits made in the editor. Updates after an undo point is reached.
        options.setup = function (ed) {
            console.log(ed)
            ed.onChange.add(function (ed, l) {
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                    modelValue(l.content);
                }
            });
        };

        //handle destroying an editor 
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce().remove() }, 0)
        });

        //$(element).tinymce(options);
        setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce(options); }, 0);
        el.html(value);

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var $element = $(element),
                       value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                       id = $element.attr('id');

        //handle programmatic updates to the observable
        // also makes sure it doesn't update it if it's the same. 
        // otherwise, it will reload the instance, causing the cursor to jump.
        if (id !== undefined) {
            var tinymceInstance = tinyMCE.get(id);
            if (!tinymceInstance)
                return;
            var content = tinymceInstance.getContent({ format: 'raw' });
            if (content !== value) {
                $element.val(value);
                //this should be more proper but ctr+c, ctr+v is broken, above need fixing
                //tinymceInstance.setContent(value,{ format: 'raw' })
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the versions of **TinyMCE** and **jQuery** that you are dependent on, you might like to try the custom binding I've recently rolled myself.

It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/tinymce-knockout-binding/)

Comment: Nice one, michaelpapworth.

Can I challenge you to include tagging/autotagging of the text into the binding? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "tagging/autotagging" within the context of the binding.  Would you mind creating an issue for this against my repository on GitHub for me to consider?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. What happened was this:

- you select Textbatch #1 and make some changes
- you switch to Textbatch #2
- the binding changes correctly from Textbatch #1 to #2
- THEN the `ed.onChange.add` event handler kicks in and overwrites the content of the *previous* Textbatch #1 with that of the *new* Textbatch #2

Take a look at this [updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xc4sz/10/show/light/) (remove /show/light from the URL to get back to the editor). I had to inline `select2.js`, because Github does not allow files it hosts to be included remotely, causing your fiddle to fail.

The important part is in `ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback`:

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
  $(element).tinymce().onChange.remove(changeHandler);

  setTimeout(function () { $(element).tinymce().remove() }, 0)
});
```

I do not know why the removal of the editor is minimally delayed with a 0-second timeout, but there is probably a good reason for that. So all we do is remove the 'change' handler, so that the old editor cannot update the bound valueAccessor in your viewmodel anymore.

EDIT: I just noticed that I fixed your fiddle, but not necessarily your original exception… here is to hoping that the two were related.

Comment: Hmm. @janfoeh, I cannot see any difference in the fiddle behavior. I still can only displayed text from the first chosen textbatch.